# docker compose linking container

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

I have two containers, one for the database (DynamoDBLocal) and the other for the web app written in Nodejs.  I use Docker compose to setup the two containers and this is what my compose file looks like.

```
version: '2'
services:
  DynamoDBLocal:
    build:
      context: ./DynamoDBLocal
    image: tags/dynamodb:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  SetupService:
    build:
      context: ./setup
    image: tags/setup_service:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

My Nodejs app speaks to the DynamoDBLocal container.  Now my problem is how do I setup the link in the compose file (.yml) and how do I change to code in the Nodejs app to refer to the new container?  My Nodejs app has code like

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "BLALBLALBLALLBLALB",
    secretAccessKey: "BLABLALBLALBLALBLLALBLALLBLALB",
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000" //Change this to new container?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the compose site you have to do 2 things: give your database container a name and link the container into your app.

```
version: '2'
services:
  DynamoDBLocal:
    container_name: DynamoDBLocal
    build:
      context: ./DynamoDBLocal
    image: tags/dynamodb:latest
  SetupService:
    build:
      context: ./setup
    image: tags/setup_service:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - DynamoDBLocal
```

you can then access the container via it's name:

```
http://DynamoDBLocal:8000
```

Comment: I actually tried this, this is what my compose file looks like
version: '2'
services:
  DynamoDBLocal:
    container_name: DynamoDBLocal
    build:
      context: ./DynamoDBLocal
    image: arjunam/drive-sync/dynamodb:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  SetupService:
    build:
      context: ./setup
    image: arjunam/drive-sync/setup_service:latest
    links:
      - "DynamoDBLocal"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

Now when I try http://DynamoDBLocal:8000 I get the

Inaccessible host: `dynamodblocal'. This service may not be available in the `us-west-2' region

Answer (score 0):

You can get your `DynamoDBLocal` host by using `SetupService`  container `ENV variables`.

```
var host = process.env.YOUR_CONTAINER_HOST_ENV_VARIABLE

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "BLALBLALBLALLBLALB",
    secretAccessKey: "BLABLALBLALBLALBLLALBLALLBLALB",
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://"+host+"8000" //Change this to new container?
});
```

Remember that linked container share all kinds of ENV variables.